# How to use a text file as database in Yii2

Tags: text, yii2, database-connection

I have to access structured text files (similar like a csv but without separator) with large amounts of data in them with yii2. I'm aware it's not a perfect way to ask this question, maybe it's a little bit too generic, but I have no idea how to do it properly in Yii2. I have searched the internet but nobody seems to have had the same task or issue.
I would like to be able to use these text files like a database. I have the definition for each field, positions and lengths, the records also have a primary key so I could reference and make connections between relevant records in different files. Has anybody tried to achieve something like this? I guess I would have to create my own DAO and yii\db\Connection and dsn. I'm aware of course, that this way I can't use SQL to query the data, it would be everything arrays. It would be nice if I could read the data first, and show in a GridView and maybe in a DetailView. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: If you only want to display list of data in grid view implementing your own data provider might be enough. But if you need database like access (search, insert, update) why not import the data file into some database first? If you are not able to use MySQL or something similar there still is SQLite which is an SQL engine over file. Trying to implement your own db-like access to text file might look reasonable at first sight but there are many problems that DB engine already has solved. For example. performance cost of search (indexes), atomicity of operations/transactions, integrity checks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I could use MySQL, but then I would have to import all the records first into the db each time when viewing, and empty again after each viewing. But it's maybe really less complicated. I could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Custom DAO:
Create a custom DAO class that will be responsible for reading and writing data to your structured text files. You can extend the yii\base\Object class or another suitable base class.

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Object;

class TextFileDAO extends Object
{
    // Implement methods for reading and writing data
}
```

Configure Database Connection:
Configure a Yii2 database connection in your application configuration (usually in config/db.php).

```
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'your_custom_dsn_here',
            // other database configurations
        ],
    ],
];
```

Implement TextFileDAO:
Implement methods in your TextFileDAO class for reading and writing data. You'll need to handle the logic for parsing the structured text files based on the field definitions, positions, lengths, and primary key information.

```
namespace app\components;

use yii\base\Object;

class TextFileDAO extends Object
{
    // Implement methods for reading and writing data

    public function find($id)
    {
        // Implement logic to find a record by primary key
    }

    public function findAll()
    {
        // Implement logic to retrieve all records
    }

    // Other methods for CRUD operations
}
```

Display Data in GridView and DetailView:
You can use the GridView and DetailView widgets provided by Yii2 to display the data. Use the methods you implemented in your TextFileDAO to fetch the data.

```
use app\components\TextFileDAO;
// ...

$textFileDAO = new TextFileDAO();
$dataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $textFileDAO->findAll(),
]);

echo \yii\grid\GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        // Define columns based on your field definitions
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Hey Chan, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm getting the following error: Cannot use yii\base\Object as Object because 'Object' is a special class name (by use yii\base\Object;)

Comment: You need to use `yii\base\BaseObject` instead of `yii\base\Object`. Since php 7.2 `object` is reserved keyword and cannot be used as name of class. The `BaseObject` class was introduced in yii2 2.0.13 to replace `Object` as base class. `yii\base\Object` is only kept around for backward compatibility purpose.