# Reading data from an ANSI text file with special characters in Yii2 is shifting values, why?

Tags: php, yii2

My question is connected to this thread: [How to use a text file as database in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77805411/how-to-use-a-text-file-as-database-in-yii2)

I have managed to read data from the structured ANSI encoded text file (no csv, but positions and lenghts of columns are specified) and show them in a gridview. I have saved the column pos and len definitions into a MySql table so I can access that. Now I'm reading these column definitions and can succesfully read each column correctly:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 1) === $type) {
        $model = new DynamicModel($dynamicAttributes);
        foreach ($fielddefs as $fielddef) {
            $attributeName = $fielddef->attributes['variable'];
            $value = substr($line, $fielddef->pos, $fielddef->len);
            $model->$attributeName = $value;
        }
        $models[] = $model;
    }
}
return $models;
```

until a special character like ü, ö etc. is present in one of the columns for example description, and in that case, the values in the next columns are shifted, so it seems that this ü is somehow changing the way how the next columns are read, the positions or lenghts are not correctly defined anymore. I was trying to convert the whole file to UTF8 with **mb_convert_encoding()** but unfortunately it didn't help. As soon as I remove any special characters like these, the whole record, all columns are read perfectly. Have you ever had something like this before? How could I fix this? Thanks.

This is how the text file looks like:

[image]

And this is how the result looks like in the gridview:

[image]

Comment: Did you try `mb_substr` (or similar ones) instead of `substr` ?

Comment: That is the solution!! Thank you very much! Sorry, haven't tried. How did you find this idea?

Comment: I was using mb_convert_encoding on each line before, that didn't help unfortunately

Comment: See whether this [sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/7968c) gives you some inspiration.

Comment: Would you please add your comment as an answer so that I can accept as solution?

Comment: `mb_convert_encoding()` is used to convert between two encodings, so it's pointless if you don't know both encodings. It's like having a currency converter and asking it convert `29.95` into €.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, which involves multi-byte characters, you will need to use `mb_substr`

```
mb_substr(
    string $string,
    int $start,
    ?int $length = null,
    ?string $encoding = null
): string
```

For your information, mb_substr performs a multi-byte safe substr() operation based on number of characters. Position is counted from the beginning of string. First character's position is 0. Second character position is 1, and so on.

You may see the effect of this function in this [sandbox](https://onlinephp.io/c/7968c)

Comment: If this answers the question, the information supplied in the question must be wrong. [ANSI encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format) are, to my knowledge, single-byte (I don't know if Chinese or Japanese Windows codepages are considered ANSI, but sample data clearly suggests European scripts).